# How to read Query Param in Response Location header in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I'm load testing my API which requires to authenticate everytime before calling the API. I need to read a query param from HTTP header "Location" and use it in further requests in Jmeter. I tried to use "Regular Expression Extractor" with `Location: .+=(.*?)\n` but it didn't work. Any ideas how to read a specific variable from response headers?

```
Location: https://<<SSO_URL>>/authenticate?code=AbCDEfg1&..... --> extract "code"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this, regex for your question is `code=([^&]*)`

[image]

Comment: This regex worked, thanks @Jyoti-Prakash-Mallick

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your regular expression to something like:

```
Location:\s* .*=(.*?)&
```

[image]

And make sure to choose `Response Headers` from the scope:

[image]

See [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of the JMeter User Manual for more details

Also it might be much easier to use the [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor), in this case you will just need to provide the "left" and "right" boundaries and it will fetch everything in-between:

[image]

Moreover it works faster and consumes less resources, see [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) article for more information